# AWS RedHat 7/8 Python version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After following the white pages on AWS I have tried a couple different EC2 instances of RedHat on aws. I cannot for the life of me install python 3.7.x

I can install python 3.6.8 by following the white pages step by step.

Is python 3.7.X supported on AWS Redhat?

Followed this page to install [White Pages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux-python.html)

Answer (score 1):

For RedHat7 and 8 I did the following to install Python 3.7.4:

1. `sudo -Es`
2. `yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel make wget`
3. `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/Python-3.7.4.tgz`
4. `tar xzf Python-3.7.4.tgz`
5. `cd Python-3.7.4`
6. `./configure --enable-optimizations`
7. `make altinstall`

You'll find `python3.7` in /usr/local/bin/

You can remove the Python3.7.4 directory when you're done with the install.

**References**

[Install Python 3.7 on CentOS](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/)

Comment: 2. does not work

bash: /bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: Any chance you can do a fresh install of RHEL?  It's probable that the work you did previously has messed up the linkage.  I've run that command twice on different fresh installs of RHEL and it worked without an issue.

Comment: yeah no problem, think it is because I already have 3.6 installed?

Comment: that worked! Thanks man!